# Ruby/Rails sample unique object from collection each time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to randomly sample one object from an collection each time while making sure everyone will be picked and when every object has been picked one time then just use sample.

So if we have the array:

```
["string1", "string2", "string3"]
```

Then on the third call to sample all object where picked. For example:

```
arr.sample
=> "string2"
arr.sample
=> "string1"
arr.sample
=> "string3"
```

How would i be able to do this using ruby/Rails?

EDIT:

When tried the methods "shuffle" and "pop" I get the error:

```
undefined method `pop' for #<File::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fa3ea5c4820>
```

Comment: Keep a shuffled copy, pop from it, once it gets empty - just sample from the original.

Comment: This is what you want? `arr.delete_at(rand(arr.size))`

Comment: You should have stated that you are not using plain Ruby array

Comment: @WandMaker I know it was my mistake

Comment: Try calling `.to_a` on that object before trying the `shuffle`.  You may want to store the output of `to_a` in a variable before trying `shuffle!`

Answer (score 10):

One solution is using `.shuffle!.pop`

```
[15] pry(main)> arr = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
=> ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
[16] pry(main)> arr.shuffle!.pop
=> "string2"
[17] pry(main)> arr.shuffle!.pop
=> "string1"
[18] pry(main)> arr.shuffle!.pop
=> "string3"
[19] pry(main)> arr.shuffle!.pop
=> nil
```

UPDATE: Since your original object is not an array but a collection, you may need to cast it to array by using `to_a` or doing this trick

```
# assume that files is your collection
m = (0..files.count-1).to_a
files[m.shuffle!.pop]
```

`files[m.shuffle!.pop]` will return a different object each time.

Comment: That's neat :) Never used `#shuffle!`.

Comment: I want them to stay in the array though and not change the order of the array too

Comment: @Tom but why? You can always copy the array first if you need the original for something.

Comment: it's says there's no such method (either shuffle or pop) on my collection

Comment: Try `to_a` as @Wand Maker's comment if you want to pop an entire File object. If you only need an attribute of File, you can try `.pluck(:an_attribute_of_file)`

Answer (score 0):

Copy array into arr2, start get samples and delete found sample, after you can do sample in original array any times you want:

```
arr = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string1"]  # Original array
arr2 = arr.inject([]) { |a,element| a << element.dup } # Get deep copy not copy by reference
arr2.uniq # remove dublicates 
(0..arr_2.length-1).each {|element| puts arr_2.delete(arr_2.sample)} # make sure all printed out just once
(0..10).each {|element| puts arr.sample} # Do sampling any times you want, here its 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array#sample` to get more than one elements, and in combination with an enumerator, you could iterate through that sample.

```
e = ["string1", "string2", "string3"].sample(3).each
e.size.times do 
    puts e.next
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this picked will give you desired result with no duplicasy:

```
selected = []
myArray = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]

# Pick from here
if myArray.sort == selected.sort
  puts '------'
  selected = []
  picked = myArray.sample
  selected << picked
else
  picked = (myArray - selected).sample
  selected << picked
end
```

If you run above code like below, You will get desired result.

```
selected = []
myArray = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
(1..10).each do |test|
    if myArray.sort == selected.sort
      selected = []
      picked = myArray.sample
      selected << picked
    else
      picked = (myArray - selected).sample
      selected << picked
    end
    puts picked
end
```

It's result something like :

```
string2
string3
string1
-------
string2
string1
string3
-------
string3
string2
string1
------
string1
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Van Huy's answer, I wasn't sure whether I would need more values than there are array entries, so instead of using pop I just walked the array in a loop and used mod to start over if I went past the end:

```
array = ["string1", "string2", "string3"].shuffle!
other_array.each_with_index do |item, i|
    item.do_something(array[i % array.length])
end
```

Thought someone might find this useful.